# Is it allowed to get in sectarian denigration in the guise of a question?

Tags: support, scope

[Did Adi Shankaracharya lose a debate against the Buddhist philosopher Vasubandhu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/818/did-adi-shankaracharya-lose-a-debate-against-the-buddhist-philosopher-vasubandhu)

This post cites a website that no longer exists and gets in denigration of Sankara under the guise of citing this website:

"
    Towards the end of his short life, defeated in debate by the Buddhist Mahapandita Vasubandhu, Adi Shankaracharya was compelled to embrace Buddhism once again, as was the norm then. He died out of the sheer shame of his defeat!

My question isn't about the claim concerning how he died; I'm pretty sure that at least Hindu sources say that he died by merging into the famous Lingam at Kedarnath to attain Moksha. "

This post is just fishing for hypothetical information under the guise of a question and better prima faciae evidence must be required before allowing such questions with transparent ulterior motives.

Comment: I guess OP's intention was not to degrade Adi Shankar. Although he doesn't accept Adi Shankar's views or philosophy but AFAIK he has respect for him. It might be other way round he might be attempting to reveal their dubious authenticity. He even used the word while starting his question.

Comment: "I am sure that at least Hindu sources say" says it all @rohit - the poster didn't bother to look up what he calls "hindu sources" say.

Comment: Yes allowed.. it depends on how much smart a user is in hiding his/her real motive.. there are many such Qs (as well as answers) whose real motives are well hidden (or not so well hidden as many of us have protested against them earlier) behind the naively and nicely poised  Qs ..

Comment: Yes, questions like [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26393/has-there-always-been-an-undercurrent-of-conflict-between-brahmins-and-kshatriya) have been asked with "transparent ulterior motives". We need to take appropriate and swift action.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I quite agree.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is primarily geared to generate division between users.

Comment: The user in question promotes posts that denigrate Sankaracharya but promptly deletes /closes any comment/ question that even remotely challenges ramanuja.

Answer (score -3):

This post

[Which scripture does Pillai Lokacharya reference in which Shiva enjoins his devotees to offer human sacrifice?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27087/which-scripture-does-pillai-lokacharya-reference-in-which-shiva-enjoins-his-devo)

is a new low for this board and illustrates this propaganda device, that seems to be used largely by a minority sect that is active here.

Does that mean any question that says "which scripture says "stuff" is always allowed?  Here "stuff" can stand for whatever horror the poster imagines pertains to Hinduism.

Another poster has joined in with this post CITING THE SAME SECTARIAN SOURCE:

[What scriptures describe Shiva discussing selling salt in the Banasura story?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27071/what-scriptures-describe-shiva-discussing-selling-salt-in-the-banasura-story)

It looks like group-posting with TWO posters citing an obscure sectarian source around the same time.